# Why is using a Result receiver for communicating between activity and fragment not considered a good practice..?

Tags: android, performance

I was studying about result receiver in android,so i found that it was a good way of communicating between activity and fragment,But i see there is no mention of result receiver being used for communication between fragment and activity.Please guide